# How to find the url of parent page of a User control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ascx, web-user-controls

I have a user control where if a certain action is performed I want to redirect to the page the user was on with some additional query string parameters.

So, if UserControl.ascx was on Home.aspx, I want to redirect to Home.aspx?action=true, and if UserControl.ascx was on Profile.aspx, I want to redirect to Profile.aspx?action=true

So basically, in my UserControl.ascx.cs I want to get the URL of the Parent Page. How can I get it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can look at the `Request.Url`, `Request.RawUrl`, `Request.FilePath`, and some of the other similar properties of the `Request` object - depending on how you're using this.

This will give you the requested URL from the browser, which will in turn tell you which page your control is living on.

Comment: Request.Url brings back a System.Uri - on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You still have access to the request object from the user control, so do something like this:

```
string currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Request.UrlReferrer will get you the URL of the previous page... usually.  There are some situations where it could be empty:

- links clicked from an email message
- shortcuts saved to a desktop
- spoofed URLs
- perhaps some settings or browsers
- probably other scenarios as well

As long as your code "plays nicely" when UrlReferrer is empty or invalid, you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host  + Request.RawUrl
```

Comment: Your response would be more helpful if you explained why it resolves the problem.